# django admin redirect I can't get a connection

Tags: django, django-admin

django admin redirect I can't get a connection.......

```
admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class RecommendLaywerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def sale(request):
        return redirect(request, "admin/sale_view.html", {})

admin.site.register(RecommendLaywer, RecommendLaywerAdmin)
```

I can't get through.........

The location of the file is as follows.

```
C:\workspace\bhsn\admin.py
```

The location of the html file is as follows:

```
C:\workspace\bhsn\template\admin\sale_view.html
```

How do I get the sales_view.html connected?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: It is not redirected to sale_view.html.

Comment: template not found error?

Comment: There is no error. I hope it's connected right away.

Comment: How do I get into the address book directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to render the template instead of redirecting to a different url, you can use render()
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

Else you will need to add the url to urls.py for the request to be redirected to. You can't redirect to a template without a url defined for it.

In regard to your code, nothing is happening because sale is defined but nothing is calling it? Something will need to use the sale method for it to be called.

Also you should pass self into the sale definition, unless it is a staticmethod.